# PHP : Error: Wrong parameters for Exception with thrown Array Exception

Tags: php, exception

I'm throwing the exception using the array like so:

```
$response = array('login_email' => '<div class="warning">Your email and / or password were incorrect</div>');

throw new \Exception($response);
```

and what I'm catching is:

```
Error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]])
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Exception() won't take an array. You need to give it a string.

```
$response = 'Your email and / or password were incorrect.';

throw new \Exception($response);
```

Read the error:

> Exception([**string** $exception [, **long** $code [, **Exception**
>   $previous = NULL]]])

Comment: That's what I thought, although I'm pretty sure in the past I've managed to pass the array as argument - thanks anyway.

Comment: If you're wanting to specify the type of Exception, you could pass it a code. new Exception($response,2);

Comment: There are also several predefined exception types in [SPL](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php), if any of those are applicable.

Comment: But they all extend the main Exception - and inherit the arguments sent to the constructor - isn't that right?

Comment: As an additional tip, in case you're using a constant as second parameter, make sure it is actually defined...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to throw an exception with an array as parameter, you can [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) your array so it becomes a string.

```
$response = array('login_email' => 'sometext', 'last_query' => 'sometext');
throw new \Exception(json_encode($response));
```

Have a look also at the second parameter of json_encode: you can add JSON_PRETTY_PRINT to have you error indented (it's more readable but it takes more space), or you can use a tool like [JSON Viewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/) for Notepad++ to format your json string when looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an exception which includes an array, then you can create your own exception class and extend it - [Can you throw an array instead of a string as an exception in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797142/can-you-throw-an-array-instead-of-a-string-as-an-exception-in-php)